# TypeORM .save changes join fields to null when leftJoin result is null

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typeorm, nest

I have this simple code in Nest. I'm trying to execute this query in TypeORM, where classes is joined with Entryxclasses and Entryxclasses is joined with TeamxClass. I am facing this issue here that if the join value of TeamxClass is null, typeorm save sets all fields used in join to null when saving the parent (Entryxclass) record.

```js
const classes = await this.classesRepo.createQueryBuilder('c')
    .where('c.customer_id = :customerId', { customerId })
    .andWhere('c.class_id IN (:...classIds)', { classIds})
    .leftJoinAndSelect('c.Entryxclasses', 'exc')
    .leftJoinAndSelect('exc.TeamxClass', 'txc')
    .getMany()

for (let trip of classes.Entryxclasses){
     trip.gone_in = true
     await this.excRepo.save(trip)
}
```

I want to save Entryxclasses record regardless of TeamxClass value.